# Mac equivalent of FinePrint's ability to merge print jobs

Tags: macos, mac, printing, fineprint

One of the nice features of (Windows only) FinePrint is that it allows you to queue several items to be printed at some stage, but only prints them when you want to. This means you can combine two documents on the same sheet (and it also means you can delete pages from a print job even after you've made the initial print request).

Is there a Mac program that can allow you to merge print jobs together?

Answer (score 2):

i think i just found an option and got what i want

once you have given the print option, in the opend window, find an option called layout where u can select how many pages per sheet.
so no need of fineprint now.

siva

Comment: Having n-up page layout is part of the solution.  However, you also need to be able to merge different print jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that does this directly.

With some extra Applescripting work you could use [PDFLab](http://www.iconus.ch/fabien/products/pleng/pleng.html). It allows you to merge PDF files from the command line, so you could make a folder action that creates a combination of all PDF files in a folder when a PDF file is added, deleting the original pdf files.

Then you'd save the documents you want to print as PDF into the special folder you set up, and when you're ready you would print the generated pdf and delete it, with another script.

Convoluted? Yes. Green? Yes.

I simply don't print anything ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Manipulate PDFs using preview](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/manipulate_pdfs_using_preview) talks about manipulating PDFs using preview, including collating documents, reordering pages and removing pages, so all you'd need to do is print the original documents to PDF. I haven't tried it myself though.